# Bootstrap - Navbar alignment

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I got the code from bootstrap to create a navbar and changed the inner text to show images. All displays well but I want to change something and I can't figure it out. This is the code I have for the navbar:

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<ul class="nav">
 <li class="active"><a href="#"><img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Dv_1JE3QwtY/UXCa6uQGgQI/AAAAAAAASok/iUT8MJ3Y_QM/s1600/Upload+Symbol.png" width="100"></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Dv_1JE3QwtY/UXCa6uQGgQI/AAAAAAAASok/iUT8MJ3Y_QM/s1600/Upload+Symbol.png" width="100"></a></li> 

 <li><a href="#"><img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Dv_1JE3QwtY/UXCa6uQGgQI/AAAAAAAASok/iUT8MJ3Y_QM/s1600/Upload+Symbol.png" width="100"></a></li> 

    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Dv_1JE3QwtY/UXCa6uQGgQI/AAAAAAAASok/iUT8MJ3Y_QM/s1600/Upload+Symbol.png" width="100"></a></li> 

</ul></div></div>
```

I've puted images in URL links so you can see better how it's now. I haven't changed the CSS from the default bootstrap one. You can just download it and simulate the navbar to see it.

PROBLEMS I HAVE

First - I want the buttons to be centered in the page. I've put text alignment center to the buttons, and even "center" tag arround it but it doesn't work. I can't figure out how to align this to the center :/

Second - if you zoom in the page, the images will stack up... i want to keep them inlign. I think i've tried to put inline on css but it didn't work either... :/

Answer (score 0):

You can positin your menu in center using code 
`.active
{
margin-left:250px;
}`
You could write this for position of your buttons. If you use bootstrap responsive it will move pictures to make it suitable for smaller resolutions. If you want your site to be fixed design dont use responsive plugin.

Comment: what you mean not use responsive plugin? i'm new to bootstrap, i've only used wordpress untill now :/

Comment: When you downlaod bootstrap within folder bootstrap you can find 3 folders. One of them is named "css". Inside of it there is file named "bootstrap-responsive.css". If you included it in your html file your design will change depending on screen resolution. Maybe I don't understand what is your problem with images. this is my view.

Comment: but html is not linked to that one. It loads bootstrap.css jquery.js and the bootstrap.min.js... it doesn't call the responsive.css